# IE7 spacing within a UL

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Can someone please explain why IE7 insists on putting a space between the table and the ul in this example?  It doesn't seem to happen in IE8 or FF.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body>
    <ul style="background-color: Blue;">
        <li>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color: Red">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img style="display: block" src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif"
                            height="25" border="0" width="150" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <ul style="background-color: Green">
                <li>One</li>
                <li>Two</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unrelated note, border="0" would be better in the css as border:none; or something

Comment: The issue is related to the img tag somehow.  I've removed the table and nested ul, and the space still appears.

Comment: Idle question: does the space still appear if you remove the display:block from the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give [hasLayout](http://haslayout.net/) to the li containing the table and ul.

```
  <ul style="background-color: Blue;">
    <li style="zoom:1;">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color: Red">
```

Comment: It was the `zoom` attribute that did it for me. What the crap is that anyway? I've been doing CSS for years and never heard of this attribute. CURSE YOU IE!!!

Answer (score 2):

All browsers have different default styles. Some make more sense than others. Try using a [CSS Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) to level the playing field, so to speak.

Comment: could not have said that better, +1

Comment: I just tried this with the example above, adding the YUI reset and the space still appears.

Answer (score 1):

I've fought this problems with Internet explorer before, and this is the solution: remove the spaces between `</td>` and `</tr>` tags. This is how your html should be:

```
</td></tr></table>
```

The browser create a TextNode between `</td>` and `</tr>` and this is the additional space you see in your page.

Comment: the rendering engine does this: s/\s+/\s/

Comment: Yes, I know the engine do that thing, but, have you tried it?

Comment: @Rodrigo. The downvote was probably because your proposed solution is irrelevant, as it makes no difference whether there's a space between the tags.

Comment: Completely agree, that bug was solved in IE7, so this response is my biggest embarrassing failure here.